# Unable to sign in to Azure subscription from visual studio 2012

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I am using Visual studio 2012 update 4 with MS Azure tools version 2.5. When tried to login to azure subscription, I got the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Did you try to update Azure tools up to 2.6? http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-6-for-net/

Comment: Yes I did. Still same issue.